# How to make ArrayList or other to work for finding a specific data in the stored list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I have written a code that takes input as Account details and displays the details by using ArrayList. I however want the list to fetch a particular/specific account details only for a data. Lets say i stored account number details for  127783  and 127784. Now i want only account number 127783 details. How do i fetch that using arrayList. If it doesn't happen with an ArrayList then what to use.

```
package com.techlabs.account;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountMenu {
    static int accountno;
    String name;
    double balance;

    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    public AccountMenu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number for the following menu :1. Open Account 2. Show Account details  "
            + "3.Retrieve details by Searching Account Number 4. Exit");    

        int number = in.nextInt();

        while (!(number == 4)) {
            if (number == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the Account no.");
                accountno = in.nextInt();
                a.add(accountno);

                System.out.println("Enter the name");
                name = in.next();
                a.add(name);

                System.out.println("Enter the Balance");
                balance = in.nextDouble();
                a.add(balance);
            }

            if (number == 2) {
                System.out.println("Account details are :");

                for (Object b : a) {
                    System.out.println(b);
                }
            }

            if (number == 3) { 
                System.out.println("Enter the account number");
                accountno=in.nextInt();

                if (a.contains(accountno)) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                }
            }

            if (number == 4) {
                System.out.println("Exit");
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the option  :1. Open Account 2. Show Account details 3.Retrieve details by Searching Account Number and 4. Exit again");
            number = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccountMenu am = new AccountMenu();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think you should use a 2d arrayList instead .Then you can just retrieve the first index and through it the corresponding array details.

Comment: You just need to create an `Account` class, which can hold the account name, account number and balance. You can then populate your list with the account. I suggest you [read the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) about creating objects. Oh, and one more thing. Format your code properly, it's very hard to read right now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping everything into a list of objects I would create a class for storing account details (with members of account number, name, balance).

I would store these in a Map < Integer, Account >. When you need a specific account's detail you can say map.get(accountNumber) and you will get back your specific Account instance.

Edit:

A wrapper class to hold Account details:

```
public Class AccountDetails{

public final int accountNumber;
public final String name;
public final int balance;

constructor
}
```

Instead of arraylist a should be:

```
Map<Integer, AccountDetails> a = new HashMap<>();
```

Where your create new accounts:

```
AccountDetails accountDetails = new AccountDetails(accountno, name, balance);
a.put(accountno, accountDetails)
```

Where you print details you should ask for the account number from the user, and after that:

```
System.out.println(a.get(accountno));
```

Of course to see something meaningful you should write a toString() method for the AccountDetails class.

Comment: I made it like this, what more changes are required. can you please change in the code                                                                                                                public class AccountMenu1 {

 Map<Integer, Account> a = new HashMap<>();
 
public AccountMenu1() {
  

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//code as above
  }
  
 }
 
}

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of errors relatying to POO in your code. Please check the code below and study OO concepts. I created a private class to represent the accounts. That way you can have an arraylist of account objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication5 {

    private static final class Account {

        int accountno;
        String name;
        double balance;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Account{" + "accountno=" + accountno + ", name=" + name + ", balance=" + balance + '}';
        }

        public void deposit(double amount){ 
              balance = balance + amount; 
        } 
        void withdraw(double amount){ 
              balance = balance-amount; 
        } 
    }

    public static void AccountMenu() {
        ArrayList<Account> a = new ArrayList();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number for the following menu :1. Open Account 2. Show Account details  "
                + "3.Retrieve details by Searching Account Number 4. Exit");
        int number = in.nextInt();

        while (!(number == 4)) {
            switch (number) {
                case 1: {
                    Account c = new Account();

                    System.out.println("Enter the Account no.");
                    c.accountno = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter the name");
                    c.name = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter the Balance");
                    c.balance = in.nextDouble();
                    a.add(c);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("Account details are :");

                    for (Account b : a) {
                        System.out.println(b);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("Enter the account number");
                    int accountno = in.nextInt();

                    for (Account account : a) {
                        if (account.accountno == accountno) {
                            System.out.println(account);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Exit");
            }
            System.out.println("Enter the number for the following menu :1. Open Account 2. Show Account details  "
                    + "3.Retrieve details by Searching Account Number 4. Exit");
            number = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccountMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i want a transaction method that makes deposit and withdraw transactions how to go about those. where to place them and how

Comment: public class AccountMenu1 {
 private static final class Account {
        int accountno;
        String name;
        double balance;

       
            
            public void transactions(double amount){
             
              deposit(){
              balance = balance + amount;
             }
             
             withdraw(){
              balance = balance-amount;
             }
            }
            
        }
    }                   But this is not a valid transaction. Please show how to do it

Comment: You have to put your methods inside the class Account but not inside the method transactions. I edited and added to my code above. Look!